# How to combine local state with Firestore stream updates using riverpod in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, riverpod

Imagine an app screen that shows a **list of ToDo Items**. The list offers the **following two functions**:

1. One of the items can be **set as a favorite** using a leading button in the list item. If one item is selected all other items are not favorited any more
2. The **items can be ordered** using a ReorderableDragStartListener()

The app **stores the ToDo items as Documents in a Firestore** collection and a **riverpod provider with an AsyncNotifier** provides these documents as a list for the UI widget.

**The ToDo item model:**

```
class ToDoItem {
 ToDoItem({
    required this.title,
    required this.order,
    required this.isFavorite
  });

  final String title;
  final int order;
  final bool isFavorite;

  ToDoItem fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ...some mapping logic;
}
```

**The riverpod Provider (simplified)**

The provider **exposes a list of ToDo items as a stream** and the notifier provides **two methods** to **change the order** and to **set one item as a favorite**:

```
@riverpod
class ToDoItemsController extends _$ToDoItemsController {
  @override
  Stream<List<ToDoItem>> build() {
    final _fs = ref.read(firestoreProvider);
    return _fs.collection('todo-items').orderBy('order').snapshots().map((snapshot) {
      return snapshot.docs.map((doc) {
        return ToDoItem.fromJson(doc.data());
      }).toList();
    });
  }

  /// Changes the order of the items
  Future<void> changeOrder(ToDoItem item, int oldIndex, int newIndex) {
    
    // 1. Change the local state to reflect the new order immediately in the UI
    final previousState = state.valueOrNull;
    if (previousState != null) {
      // ...Logic of changing the local state here...
    }

    // 2. Update the firestore documents to reflect the new order
    _fs.collection(.... // ...Logic of updating the firestore documents here...
  }

  // Sets an item as favorite.
  Future<void> setFavoriteToDoItem(ToDoItem item) {
    
    // 1. Change the local state to reflect the new order immediately in the UI
    final newList = ... // Logic of changing the local state here...
    state = newList;

    // 2. Update the firestore documents to reflect the new order
    _fs.collection(... // Logic of updating the firestore documents here...
  }
}
```

**And here is my issue / question:**
To reflect changes of the favorite state and the ordering of the items **immediately** these methods first change the local state and then ask Firestore to update the documents accordingly. Without manual state change the UI doesn´t feel responsive/reactive due to the delay between updating the Firestore document and getting the new stream event.

**Problem with Favorites**
The problem with the favorites is, that the widget is finally rebuilt three times:

1. Manual state change
2. First Stream update when the document with the old favorite state is set to false
3. Second Stream update when the document with the new favorite state is set to true
   -> That leads to flickering in the UI (forth and back)

**Problem with ordering**
Nearly the same issue as with the favorites, besides here the items jump back and forth after reordering, also caused by multiple document updates / stream events.

Now I´m wondering **how to reflect changes of the local state immediately** in the UI, **update firestore documents optimistically** AND **use a stream listener** to receive the documents. Some ideas:

- Put favorites and order in own documents (which feels a bit over engineered to me)
- Maybe there is a way to update documents and tell firestore to not emit a new event on that concrete document operation?